# Using D3 to for Literary Data

Tags: d3.js

I've been teaching myself D3 in order to experiment with alternative approaches to teaching literature. One of the problems I keep running in to is how to represent time in a literary work to D3. For example, if I'm trying to visualize word frequency in Macbeth, I have time data in the form of Acts/Scenes/Line#, but not dates.  Many of the D3 templates are date-centric, which presents a problem for me.  Can anyone provide guidance to a novice on this?

A thousand thank yous, 
Tom

Comment: I'm not sure I see how you are going to use "time" exactly. A bubble cloud type chart is often used for this sort of thing. Something like this: http://vallandingham.me/bubble_cloud/

Comment: You've likely seen them already, but these come to mind: the [Les Miserables](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/) interactive; [this print graphic](https://www.behance.net/gallery/18722455/The-real-Montalbano) visualizing 19 novels. I agree that visualizations of works of literature don't usually call for building precise timelines. Seems like you would want to look more into the qualitative features of d3. Things like `d3.scale.ordinal`, `d3.layout.force`, `d3.layout.hierarchy`.

Comment: Almost anywhere d3 charts use a date value for the x axis, you can use another quantitative value, such as scene (assuming you have that data).  What exact visualization do you have in mind for word frequency?  A bar chart for word count per scene?  Line chart?